# Telegram Bot that takes data from input form and sends it to a telegram group/user

Tags: curl, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to help a friend. He has a simple site made with HTML, JavaScript and jQuery. He needs to integrate the site with telegram so, that if someone fills the form on the site, the telegram bot should send the information in a group chat (I know how to take the chat_id, but nothing more about telegram bots).

So I tried to send some POST requests with curl to my bot with the sendMessage method, but it seems it didnt worked.

Maybe I made mistake with the command line curl, it doesnt show me any output when I make a request. I`ve found that it sends the output in stdout (whatever this is...)

So I have 2 questions:

1: How can I make curl show the response output in the command line?

2: How do I make the request to send a message to myself (In telegram bot manual it says it should look like this below..)

```
curl -s \
-X POST \
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage \
-d text="A message from your bot" \
-d chat_id=65535 \
| jq .
```

I assumed I need to write that in cmd I tried with my personal bot token and chat_id but It didnt work.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a simple GET request also to make the Bot send a message.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?text=Your message here&chat_id=65535
```

Below is a sample code you can make use of.

```js
function sendmessage(){
  chat_id = document.getElementById("chatid").value;
  token = document.getElementById("token").value;
  message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  $.get("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendMessage?text="+message+"&chat_id="+chat_id);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="chatid" value="Chat ID"></br>
<input type="text" id="token" value="Bot Token"></br>
<input type="text" id="message" value="Message"></br>
<button onclick=sendmessage()>Send Message</button>
```